# Is AIX 7.2 supported by some version of Go?

Tags: go, aix

I am working on IBM AIX 7.2, and now I want to use Go on it.

Is there any gc (not gccgo) version that supports AIX 7.2?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-open-source-software-downloads-alpha#G

Comment: Note that the difference in the Go compiler implemented by gc (what you call "google golang") and gcc is neglible as they basically are the same.

Comment: @Volker How exactly are gc and gccgo "the same"?

Comment: Written by the same person(s), using the same runtime and the same stdlib. Only the code generation (and linking) part is different.

Comment: @Volker "Written by the same people" makes it "the same"?  And here is at least one major difference between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67659524/is-gos-stack-split-or-stack-copy/67659651#67659651

Comment: Might have already said, but Aix is exotic enough in itself, there is no need to add an exotic language on top if it (before you ask: yes, I wouldn't use Swift/Rust/Go/C++/C# on Aix either)

Answer (score 2):

Run this command to see supported Architectures

```
go tool dist list
```

output:

```
aix/ppc64
android/386
android/amd64
android/arm
android/arm64
darwin/amd64
darwin/arm64
dragonfly/amd64
freebsd/386
freebsd/amd64
freebsd/arm
freebsd/arm64
illumos/amd64
ios/amd64
ios/arm64
js/wasm
linux/386
linux/amd64
linux/arm
linux/arm64
linux/mips
linux/mips64
linux/mips64le
linux/mipsle
linux/ppc64
linux/ppc64le
linux/riscv64
linux/s390x
netbsd/386
netbsd/amd64
netbsd/arm
netbsd/arm64
openbsd/386
openbsd/amd64
openbsd/arm
openbsd/arm64
openbsd/mips64
plan9/386
plan9/amd64
plan9/arm
solaris/amd64
windows/386
windows/amd64
windows/arm
windows/arm64
```